# Wii balance board sampling frequency

Tags: hardware

I'm looking for the maximum sampling rate of the Wii Balance Board for studying [statokinesiograms](http://www.cq.com.pl/e_stabilograf.html) (2D path of the ground projection of the center of pressure). Some [source](http://marcocardinale.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/nintendo-wii-fit-can-be-used-as-a-force-plate/) indicates a sampling rate of 100Hz. [Another](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/wii-balance-board2.htm) mentions 60Hz, and a [serious reference](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S096663620900664X) is using the WBB at 40Hz !

The related [patent](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/20090093305.pdf) does not provide this information but mention 60Hz "as an example" (page 13). I suppose the bottleneck in frequency would be the microprocessor speed, as several pressure acquisitions could be transmitted at once with the bluetooth module.

Answer (score 3):

After having performed a few tests, we derived this histogram of the interval between two successive data points received. The largest peak correspond to a frequency of 40Hz.
[image]